# PHP code for adding incrementing css ID's to generated list

Tags: php, increment

I have a bit of PHP code that pulls images from a directory and displays them as

elements with added css classes. The code also adds incrementing css ID's to each list item and this is what i'm having trouble with.

If you check my code below you will that the list ID's are incrementing properly but the variable **$i** is being echoed as text along with the images. I am trying to get the ID's to increment but I do not want the variable to be echoed. I know the answer is staring me in the face but for the life of me I can't see it being a bit of a PHP novice.

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php

$files = glob("images/assets/*.{png,jpg,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE);
$i = 1;
foreach ($files as $file)


    echo "<li id:\"S-$i\"><img class=\"zuper\" src=\"$file\" /></li>",

    $i++;

?>
```

**Generated HTML**

```
<li id:"S-1"><img class="zuper" src="images/assets/1.jpg" /></li>1
<li id:"S-2"><img class="zuper" src="images/assets/2.jpg" /></li>2
<li id:"S-3"><img class="zuper" src="images/assets/3.jpg" /></li>3
<li id:"S-4"><img class="zuper" src="images/assets/4.jpg" /></li>4
<li id:"S-5"><img class="zuper" src="images/assets/5.jpg" /></li>5
<li id:"S-6"><img class="zuper" src="images/assets/bistro.jpg" /></li>6
<li id:"S-7"><img class="zuper" src="images/assets/hotel.jpg" /></li>7
<li id:"S-8"><img class="zuper" src="images/assets/view.jpg" /></li>8
<li id:"S-9"><img class="zuper" src="images/assets/weddings.jpg" /></li>9
```

You can see in the generated HTML that the variable $i is being echoed after each

Comment: The echo stops when you break it with `;` sign. You have written a `,` which makes it echo the $i++

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
echo "<li id:\"S-$i\"><img class=\"zuper\" src=\"$file\" /></li>",

$i++;
```

to

```
echo "<li id:\"S-$i\"><img class=\"zuper\" src=\"$file\" /></li>";

$i++;
```

Note how I changed **,** to **;**. See [Instruction Separation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php).

Comment: Yep, it was staring me in the face!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your html be:

```
<li id="S-1">....
```

Not

```
<li id:"S-1">....
```